# SugarCRM Products has no Sub-Panel

Tags: sugarcrm

I created a relationship between a custom module and products which seems to work.  The only problem is, I want to list the products on the custom module as a sub panel but Products does not have a sub panel.  Any way to create this?

Comment: I just went and looked at our instance and we have a many-to-many relationship between products and contracts, and there is a subpanel for each in the other. What version of Sugar are you on (probably 6.1, right?)  What type of relationship is it (one-to-one, one-to-many, many-to-many)?

Comment: I just created a new module for my products with a one to many relationship and it works fine.  Just not going to use the default products module

Answer (score 1):

My best bet is that you might have created a relationship that doesn't create a subpanel on the desired module end. For example 1-N contacts-products, in this case products won't have a subpanel but only relate field since there can only be one contact associated with a product.